# Pagination count issue in active admin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, activeadmin, will-paginate, kaminari

I am using Active admin and I am trying to add pagination for one of my tables

```
  paginated_collection(histories.page(params[:page]).per(5), download_links: false) do
        table_for collection do
          column ('Status') { |bh| bh.status.humanize }
          column ('Reason') { |bh| bh.reason }
          column ('Date') { |bh| bh.created_at }
        end
      end
```

I added a module as there is conflict between will_paginate and kaminari(ref: https://tech-brains.blogspot.com/2012/11/kaminari-willpaginate-incompatibility.html)

In pagination links it displays invalid count as in below picture(The table has 6 records totally and I have paginated with 5 records per page, In first page link it displays(1-6) and in second page links it displays(6-11)),

[image]
[image: Total count in the page is only 6 but it displays wrong count],

Comment: did you see [this](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/0-installation.md#will_paginate) in the active admin docs?
"If you use will_paginate in your app, you need to configure an initializer for Kaminari to avoid conflicts."

`# config/initializers/kaminari.rb
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
end`

Comment: Yes, I have added that.